# Android regex pattern get amount with $

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to get the current amount from this string, but I only want the double.

```
String total = "Your current total is +$35.25";
```

I have tried this code, but the `$` means end of line and it always returns `0.00`, so how can I only get the `35.25`

```
double amount = getNumberFromString("(\\$\\d\\d.?\\d?\\d?)\\s?[^Xx]?", total);

public double getNumberFromString(String value, final String s)
{
    double n = 0.0;
    Matcher M = Pattern.compile(value).matcher(s);

    while (((Matcher)M).find())
    {
        try {
            n = Double.parseDouble(((Matcher)M).group(1));
            //Log.e(TAG, "Number is : " + ((Matcher)M).group(1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            n = 0.0;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: @anubhava still same result, comes back as 0.0

Comment: `double amount = getNumberFromString("\\$(\\d+\\.\\d+)", total);` So that `$` is outside group 1.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, that one does work. I also used https://regexr.com/ to confirm it. I appreciate the fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is throwing exception because your regex is capturing non-numeric `$` in group #1. Also note that your code is doing unnecessary casting that can be avoided.

Following code should work for you:

```
String total = "Your current total is +$35.25"; 

double amount = getNumberFromString("\\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", total);

public double getNumberFromString(String value, final String s) {
    double n = 0.0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(value).matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        try {
            n = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            n = 0.0;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works like a charm. I truly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I trieds this regex and it returns the number, though it doesn't take into account other formattig characters you may have like ',' for thousands separation.

Also if for the sign it could be negative, then you can replace the `'\\+'` by `[\\+-]`

```
double amount = getNumberFromString("^Your current total is \\+\\$(\\d+\\.\\d{2})$", total);
```